# Error setting up the address bar for Google search engine

Tags: epiphany

I installed the Russian version of the operating system (the problem may be repeated in operating systems in other languages). An error occurred while trying to search in Epiphany. It is related to the fact that Google is selected by default for search, but in the settings instead of https://google.com/search?q=%s or https://google.ru/search?q=%s specified https://google./search?q=%s, respectively, the request does not occur because the google.-erver not exist. Of course, I can fix the error manually on my version of the operating system, but I would like it to be fixed for all users in the update. This will improve the perception of the system.

Comment: I agree with you completely, but the place that you need to put this kind of feedback to the developpers is https://github.com/elementary . I believe they read here also, but elementaryos.stackexchange is mostly used for questions and answers between the users of the elementary OS, the issue quenue is on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is fixed in Epiphany 3.32.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/commit/db1b1c60d3167064c547ba9416a821ba4be641ee) I don't know when elementary OS will update to a newer version of Epiphany.